# Rashi's biography sources

Tags: history, rashi, sources-mekorot

I know that Rashi had daughters — either two or three — and no sons. I also know he was a vintner — meaning he made wine. I know he was a student of or student of a student of Rabenu Gershom. I guess I know this all from my schooling. My question is: Where is the source of all this information in classical Judaic sources? Meaning not a recent professor's, or any professor's, thesis, but a source in the rabbinic literature.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27823

Comment: Actualy, R. Dr. Hayyim Soloveitchik casts doubt on the assertion that he was a vintner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Seder HaDoros](http://books.google.com/books?id=1-U-AAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a lot of the popular information that we know about Rashi, see the sources that he brings.