# Teffilin For Women

Tags: women, tefilin

Can women wear Tefilin (I know they are exempt but a women gets schar for mitzvos they are not commanded to so is it allowed)? If it’s kli gever, what has distinguished it as such?
What is the majority view, and the main reasons (not) to wear them?

Comment: I understand that they are exempt but are they prohibited?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate between Danno's link and this: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27823

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLglPcqrwirN6wNa3JXDgo858aiAdX3VRM

Answer (score 0):

The Levush 17:2 holds its prohibited based off the issur of shmolas beged ish(wearing clothing of the opposite gender) Targum Yonasan says the same. The Biur Gra 38:3  held its assur.

Comment: Can you explain the rule. Shmolas Beged Ish.?

Comment: Targum Yonasan doesn't add much to your argument.

Comment: Do we know if the Levush still applies?

Comment: @doubleaa I know you don't like it from a diff time ,but the poskim quote it .

Comment: @sam They do, because it's the best they can do.

Comment: Can you explain the rule. Shmolas Beged Ish?

Comment: Why don't you ask it as a question

Comment: @doubleaa ,why would the Levush not be applicable anymore,you can read it here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44268&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=

Comment: @sam Because most everyone agrees that questions of assigning genders to clothing are time and location dependent
.

Comment: @doubleaa well if you read it inside you will see he mentions Michal how she was allowed to wear it and explains a Bas Melech is diff,meaning it is always beged Ish and really can't be changed it seems that it may have become an inherent beged Ish,read it for your own idea