# How could anyone think Rashi's daughters wore Tefillin?

Tags: women, mitzvah, tefilin, rashi, time-bound

There is a widely-held theory that Rashi's daughters wore Tefillin.

Rashi [here](http://sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.33a.5?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) seems to say there is a Bal Tosif (prohibition to add on a commandment) if a women does a Mitzvat Aseh Shehazman Grama (time-bound Mitzvah).

If so, it would seem impossible that Rashi's daughters wore Tefillin.

Am I correct in my analysis?

Comment: He's saying that for Rabbi Yehuda. Maybe the halacha is like Rabbi Yossi?

Comment: yes, if you want, make this an answer and I will give you points.

Comment: By this logic it would seem impossible that Rabbenu Tam wore Rabbenu Tam Tefillin.

Comment: @DoubleAA well I guess he's assuming Rashi's daughters "wore tefillin" while living with him, and he wouldn't have allowed  them to transgress Bal Tosif

Comment: if your analysis is correct then women should walk out fo shul before shofar blowing.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27823/rashis-daughters-wearing-tefillin

Comment: @DannySchoemann obviously we do not pasken that way, but it seems that Rashi could hold so. I think the Maharsha has major Kashyas on Rashi on this point.

Comment: Maybe in the assumed story, Rashi's daughter's didn't hold of his psak. Might explain where their kids got it from.

Comment: I think your first title made more sense. If you disagree you can change it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no evidence that Rashi's daughter wore Tefillin but Rashi frequently explains the Gemora according to the hava amina and not according to halacha l'maaseh so this Rashi in itself doesn't prove he actually held that way.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.96a.13?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) also says the opposite on the  Gemara ([Eiruvin 96A](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.96a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) which says Michal Bas Shaul wore tefillin  but the Chachamim did not protest (which is where I'm guessing this concept came from, people are mistaking whose daughter wore tefillin) Rashi explains they did not protest that she is  being oiver on Baal Tosif.

In both Gemoras, Rashi is explaining according to that hava amina and not necessarily saying a halacha l'maaseh.